# Where can I edit the inline code style for a Jekyll blog?

Tags: css, jekyll

I'm trying to set up the styling of my Jekyll blog. I've noticed that the inline code highlighting that uses the two backticks `.[image]

Here you can see the inline highlighting style is very different to the code block styling. The code block styling is done in the `_highlighter.scss` file. Any ideas where I can edit the style of the inline code?

Comment: What do you mean by inline code, special styles for a code block? Also which theme are you using?

Comment: I mean using backticks. You can see above the word `scope` is different styling to the code box. The code in the box is wrapped around `{% highlight swift %}` and `{% endhighlight %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style location may vary depending on several factors:

- the theme you are using and if that theme is customized
- the syntax highlighter engine

In a standard Jekyll instance, inline code blocks will start like `<code class="highlighter-rouge>`, that is, the style would be a mix of the `code` tag and the above class.

The easiest way to find out where to change your jekyll instance styling is to use the browser **[inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles)** code mode, that will show you which file and style to change.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to find the blocks to edit just with trial and error!